# is it possible to run a python script without saving it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have tried RUN a script that was commented and saved, so. When I uncommented a part of code without save the script, it run but, it takes like if it's still commented. I had to save the script with the part uncommented.

Comment: Yes, if you don’t save the file, it’s not written to disk, and Python can’t read your changes.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted and closed. You don't have to save things in all execution environments (jupyter notebook comes to mind). And the provided answer is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

However, you can modify a VS Code setting `files.autoSave` to auto save a file automatically.
Also, take a look at `files.autoSaveDelay` setting if it suits your needs.